# Redirecting SVN working copy to other remote location

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is there a way to redirect SVN repository? I have a local working copy that is pointing to remote main\locationA. I would like it to be pointing to main\locationB. Is there a way to do it without moving files from the local working copy location? this files are jenkins configuration stored in JENKINS_path so i wouldn't like to loose them or put them elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

`svn help relocate` - if I read your request correctly. This way you'll change mounting pointbase of the whole WC from OLD-REPOURL to NEW-REPOURL for all it's subtrees

Comment: I don't think it will do what i want. The problem is that i have newer revision in remote repo and older in my working copy. I don't want to do update my working copy, so that svn won't update my files with remote files. but i want to overwrite all content of remote with my local version. It sounds pretty straightforward but i keep getting errors, i thought changing to other location with whole repo will help but it seems not that simple too.

Comment: @Biba - it's another story: branch your WC, merge branch to trunk with `--accept tf` (can't recall setting in TSVN)